# Heroku error: bash: web:: command not found

Tags: python, django, heroku

Today my Heroku website was working fine but then I had to make lots of changes to the file and I definitely did something to it because now it doesn't work anymore. I don't know what could've changed the configuration.

Here is my `Procfile`:

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --no-input; web: gunicorn --pythonpath ghiblimovs mysite.wsgi --log-file
```

Here are my settings:

```
import os
import dj_database_url

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'secretkeyhere'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'core',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
         ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'djangogirls',
        'USER': 'name',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
        }
}

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
    
)
```

This is the error I get when I push to Heroku:

```
2020-08-17T23:28:59.916852+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py collectstatic --no-input; web: gunicorn --pythonpath ghiblimovs mysite.wsgi --log-file -`
2020-08-17T23:29:03.838564+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-08-17T23:29:03.838591+00:00 app[web.1]: 119 static files copied to '/app/staticfiles', 1 unmodified, 276 post-processed.
2020-08-17T23:29:03.880853+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: web:: command not found
2020-08-17T23:29:03.926388+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2020-08-17T23:29:03.961012+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-17T23:29:05.298138+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ghiblimovs.herokuapp.com request_id=8114d978-cb22-45f4-9b6b-618fab619c64 fwd="190.244.95.189" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-17T23:29:05.963051+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ghiblimovs.herokuapp.com request_id=5a4940b9-b172-43ec-83db-6457680c6d37 fwd="190.244.95.189" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Any help would be useful!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your `Procfile`.

Comment: Also, consider diffing against whatever revision worked before to see what you've changed.

Comment: @Chris I modified it and yes, I should do that from now on

Comment: You appear to be trying to define two different `web` processes. Why?

Comment: Oh, I wanted heroku to collect the static, maybe that's the issue then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Procfile` is broken:

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --no-input; web: gunicorn --pythonpath ghiblimovs mysite.wsgi --log-file
```

You're cramming two `web` process definitions into one line.

If you really want to chain things there, use `&&`:

```
web: python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && gunicorn --pythonpath ghiblimovs mysite.wsgi --log-file -
```

But [Heroku runs `collectstatic` for Django applications by default](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#collectstatic-during-builds). You don't need to put that in the `Procfile`. Something like this should do:

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath ghiblimovs mysite.wsgi --log-file -
```

Note that you were also missing the `-` argument to `--log-file`. I've added it here.

Answer (score -2):

web: gunicorn --pythonpath ghiblimovs mysite.wsgi --log-file

Answer gunicorn: pip install gunicorn

In your Procfile(letter p should spell Capital letter)
in Procfile type code:
web: gunicorn  mysite.wsgi
The app creash is cause of bad header request
rest the heroku logs history setting folling you commit message.

Comment: ...none of this is relevant. OP's `Pipfile` is already named correctly, otherwise its contents would be ignored. They should already have `gunicorn` installed since the application worked before, and `pip install` won't work on Heroku anyway. Nothing above suggests that `gunicorn` is missing. This has nothing to do with a "bad header request", whatever that is. And I have no idea what "rest the heroku logs history setting folling you commit message" is supposed to mean.